# Bakoma Tex software

Tags: installing, distributions, software, bakoma

Bakoma Tex software has stopped its services. I purchased the latest version, but now I am unable to install a new system.

How to transfer the existing BaKoMa files to a new system?

Comment: Welcome! What kind of files are you trying to transfer exactly? Are you asking about copying programme files? Or about copying documents?

Comment: Probably programme files. The website for BaKoMa TeX seems to have been sold, so my guess is that downloads and activation of BaKoMa no longer work. (Incidentally, it is not great now that CTAN mirrors all have links pointing to the defunct website, that is now hosting something probably shady.)

Comment: Not sold, just never renewed... and when it's hold period lapsed someone jumped on picking it up to put a shady gambling site in its place; probably in hopes that the original site owner would pay to have it transferred back.

Answer (score 6):

The official BaKoMa TeX homepage is no longer available, please go to the new homepage https://bakoma-tex.daniel-aldrich.ca/. To find out how to register, join the Discord community at https://discord.com/invite/kY4WSmuzx8.

Comment: I suppose anyone who wants WYSIWYG in their LaTeX can figure out Discord, too … I'm officially old, if it needed any further proof.

Comment: This is only temporary... when I have the time to implement everything, these methods will be added to the website. Discord was an easy setup for the community but more accessible means need to exist as well.